# Running ruby gem sprockets from command line

Tags: ruby, command-line, sprockets

I am finding very little documentation on running sprockets from the command line.

Does anyone know how to setup the .sprocketsrc file?

Examples would be great especially on how to configure the minification.

Comment: I do not, but you may be interested in middleman, which wraps sprockets in it's own stuff meant for command line execution, and is somewhat better documented than raw sprockets.

Answer (score 0):

If you read directly the source, you can see there https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/bin/sprockets#L8 that it uses something named Shellwords which comes with the standard ruby library : http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html and http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellsplit

So we can guess from :

```
  unless ARGV.delete("--noenv")
    if File.exist?(path = "./.sprocketsrc")
      rcflags = Shellwords.split(File.read(path))
      ARGV.unshift(*rcflags)
    end
  end
```

That it basically prepends whatever it find in the sprocketsrc to the command line arguments.

https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/bin/sprockets#L22 gives us the list of the options, meaning if you want to configure the minification you can create a .sprocketsrc

with something like

```
--include=assets/javascripts --output build/assets/javascripts
```

Sadly, the command line don't look to have any option to configure the minifying options.